# Дефис между одинаковыми словами

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Никак не могу разобраться, когда нужно ставить дефис между одинаковыми словами, а когда ставится запятая. Например, в таком случае: "Нет(-)нет, что ты!" Или эмоциональное подтверждение: "Точно(-)точно!"
Буду благодарна за помощь.

Comment: Сердце стучит: тук, тук, тук, тук, ...

Сердце стучит: тук-тук, тук-тук, ...

Сколько в кулачке надежд осталось?! Нечет-чёт, и снова нечет-чёт.

Comment: Вот как стучит, так и пишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысловое значение повтора примерно одно и то же - он усиливает эмоциональную выразительность текста. Для этого используются две формы, которые хорошо различаются на слух.

При дефисной форме написания это осложненное слово с одним ударением: Нет-нет, что ты!

Вот интересный поэтический пример: "Мы - просто недвижимость, непонятно чья. Мы - судьи всему миру, и Бог нам не судья. Мы точно-точно выживем, храня только себя. … Закрывшись в своей комнате не проследим черты. Мы точно-точно выживем, ведь мы уже мертвы".

Если мы ставим запятую, то повторяющиеся слова являются однородными и произносятся с перечислительной интонацией (с тоническим ударением на каждом слове). Этот прием часто используется в литературе: «Но бедный, бедный мой Евгений... «Страшно, страшно поневоле / Средь неведомых равнин!» "Дух бродяжий, ты все реже, реже расшевеливаешь пламень уст".