# "Нет-нет" в разговорной речи

Tags: разговорная-речь

Будьте добры, подскажите, можно ли ставить дефис в данном случае:

Нет-нет, в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29783/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8.

Answer (score 1):

Не только можно, но и нужно: нет интонации перечисления.

[Вопрос № 255306](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20255306)

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, стоит ли ставить запятую между
> повторяющимися словами в следующих примерах:
>
> Нет_нет, я с вами не согласен. Да_да, я сама всё видела.
>
> Спасибо!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Лучше поставить дефис: *нет-нет, да-да.*

См. также: [Дефисное написание повторяемых сочетаний](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

---

[Как правильно пишется "Да да да"? Через дефис или запятую?](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/128257762108)

Разграничение написаний: 1) да, да (через запятую); 2) да-да (с дефисом); 3) да — да (через тире) — связано с различием в их значениях. Ср.: *Я люблю её! Да, да!* (Герц.) — усиленное утверждение, в значениях «конечно», «совершенно верно»; *Он поспешил согласиться: «Да-да, обязательно»* — экспрессивно выраженное подтверждение, с оттенком торопливости, нетерпения; *Терять ему было нечего: да — да, нет — нет* — в значении «если да, то да, если нет, то нет».
Междометие "да-да-да" пишется через дефис.